# sock.js not allowing POST method for node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, sockjs

Trying to bring up a node server that uses sock.js for websocket communication.

Can bring up the server fine and have established the websocket communication. However, we also need to POST to this instance with HTTP so that we can  then send a message through the websocket. The message is dependent on the POST payload...

However, sock.js does not seem to be accepting the handler that we're creating, and is only allowing a GET method. This is causing a 405 HTTP code for any POSTs done to the server.

Please see following code. If I remove the sock.js implementation, I'm then able to process GET and POST requests with the server.

```
var app = require('http');
var sockjs = require('sockjs');
var sk = sockjs.createServer({ sockjs_url: '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/1.0.1/sockjs.min.js' });

sk.on('connection', function (conn) {
    console.log('connection' + conn);
    conn.on('close', function () {
        console.log('close ' + conn);
    });
    conn.on('data', function (message) {
        console.log('message ' + conn,
                message);

        conn.write(message);
    });

});

var server = app.createServer( function(req, res) {

    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        console.log("POST");
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
            console.log("Partial body: " + body);
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            console.log("Body: " + body);
        });
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end('post received');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("GET");

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end('get received');
    }

});

sk.installHandlers(server);
```

I've tried different ways to set up the handlers, including following the example [here](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/blob/master/examples/echo/server.js); but regardless it just doesn't seem like I'm falling into my handlers but instead sock.js is not allowing POSTs.

If this is expected behavior from sock.js and is working the way it;s intended to, then recommendations for what to use would be appreciated. This is an attempt to move away from socket.io because that isn't working in all cases for us... but without being able to POST to the node server we probably won't be able to use sock.js either.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question, but can't you just run them on different ports?

Comment: I would recommend you use more descriptive names for your variables... `app` is confusing, you should probably use `http` instead. Ditto `server` -> `httpserver`.

Comment: @jcaron, I agree about the naming. This is just a prototype for me to understand how it works. The production code will be named more appropriately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `prefix` in your call to `installHandlers`. This results in `sockjs` handling all requests, rather than just those that are destined to it.

Just specify a prefix:

```
sk.installHandler(server,{prefix:"/whatever"});
```

It should of course match the prefix you use client-side.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use a prefix, use different ports.

Comment: I had tried the prefix before with the same 405 HTTP error code. However, after your post what I did was re-set the prefix definition in there, but try different resources. So instead of /whatever, I would try /whoever. And that worked -- meaning sock.js manages anything coming down the prefix path (in this case /whatever), but lets everything else through to the rest of the node server handlers. That's incredibly easy to understand now that I see it working, but took a while for it to sink in. I appreciate the help!